# Create Media File To Save Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera, media

I am making an android app which requires to take a photo and save it.
In this method I am trying to make a file to save that image but it returns null. Can someone help?

```
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
    Environment
        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "weatherapp");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("weatherapp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
        .format(new Date(0));
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
        + "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: When you say that your method is returning null, is it returning null after logging "failed to create directory" or is it returning a null `mediaFile` object?

Comment: it is returning a null media file object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `File(String path)` constructor, try `File(File dir, String name)`.

```
File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir, "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to check permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```